# (QT C++) Animate GIF Based on Slider/Dial Value

Tags: c++, qt, slider, frame, gif

I am relatively new to Qt and I have a question that seems simple enough.

How could I make a slider/line edit thingy that when set to a certain value (0) it displays the beginning of a GIF animation, then when set to a higher value (12000) it goes to a frame further in the animation? The GIF image would be next to the slider, not a separate window. Pretty much any way to do this is accepted.
:)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `QMovie` to operate animated GIF image. You need to set `QMovie::CacheAll` cache mode in order to make rewinding backwards possible. Put a slider and a label in your form. Add `QMovie* movie` private class member.

In the constructor:

```
movie = new QMovie("c:/tmp/sample.gif", "GIF", this);
movie->setCacheMode(QMovie::CacheAll);
ui->slider->setRange(0, movie->frameCount() - 1);
on_slider_valueChanged(0);
```

In the slot:

```
void MainWindow::on_slider_valueChanged(int value) {
  movie->jumpToFrame(value);
  ui->label->setPixmap(movie->currentPixmap());
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `movie->frameCount()-1` instead?